# Port forwarding with nginx from java

Tags: java, ssl, https, nginx, redis

I'm trying to make a **java application** which uses **redis** as a backend. Since **Redis** is a really fast key-value store which I'd like to use, but **redis** is made to be used with 1 client so it doesn't have an option for user:pass authentication. I'd like to find a way to implement some kind of authentication, so I tried **nginx** with the **redis2** extension. I did this because I could use **client-side certficates** and HTTPS. But it's making my application really slow.

I'm thinking about using some kind of tunnel which connects to redis via **nginx proxy**. For this redis would be listen on localhost and there would be an address which I'd like to use to reach redis, but with https authentication. So basically my current method

```
JAVA - Jedis - LAN - REDIS ,would be 
JAVA - Jedis(with localhost as the tunnel entrance?)-
-SSL LAN - Nginx(tunnel exit) - Redis
```

Any tip for achieving this? I've been googled the web for the last days but i couldn't come up anything that adds only a little overhead to the native connection.

Comment: You have some important misconceptions about Redis. First, Redis is decidedly not designed to be used for one client only. It efficiently handles thousands of concurrent clients. Second, it does in fact have an authentication mechanism, though it is a global access level permission.

Further, I'm pretty sure what you are trying with Nginx will require a lot more than some configuration. You will need to write a proxy relay to do it, you can't just put Nginx in front of Redis as Nginx is HTTP (and has modules for POP and SMTP) & call it good. Perhaps you can add details on your setup & reqs.

Comment: In addition, I can't see the value of direct Redis connections. Redis is storage. It requires logic to find the data you want. Putting all that logic in a client (say a mobile app), bloats the client and presents an upgrade nightmare, that is easily avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis is designed to work on a secure network, behind a backend application. Client applications are not supposed to connect directly to Redis. It makes Redis a poor choice for a 2-tier application.

Now if you still want to use Redis for this, you have several options. You can encapsulate the Redis server in a HTTP interface. This is what the nginx redis2 module provide. You might also want to have a look at [webdis](http://webd.is/), which is similar (and does not depend on nginx). Webdis offers some access control mechanisms. See the documentation.

Another solution is to establish a tunnel, as you proposed. I would not use nginx for this, but just plain old SSH. Let's suppose Redis server runs on machine B (port 6379)  and client runs on machine A.

On machine A, I can run:

```
ssh user@host_B -L 7008:host_B:6379 -N
```

It will open a tunnel from A to B from local port 7008 (arbitrary choice), and waits. The user should be declared on host B, and its password known. In another session, still on host A, we can now run:

```
redis-cli -p 7008 ping
```

Please note a standard Redis client is used. The tunnel handles authentication, encryption and optionally compression in a transparent way for the client.

Now, your client is a Java application, and you probably do not want to run SSH commands to setup the tunnel. Hopefully, you can use the [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) package to open the tunnel directly from Java. Here is an example with Jedis:

```
import redis.clients.jedis.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

public class TestTunnel {

    Jedis jedis;  
    Session session;
    JSch jsch = new JSch(); 
    int port;

    // None of the following should be hardcoded
    static String USER = "user";          // SSH user on the redis server host
    static String PASSWD = "XXXXXXXX";    // SSH user password
    static String HOST = "192.168.1.62";  // Redis server host
    static int PORT = 6379;               // Redis server port

    public TestTunnel() {
      try {
        // Open the SSH session
        session = jsch.getSession( USER, HOST, 22 );
        session.setPassword( PASSWD );
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("Compression", "yes");
        config.put("ConnectionAttempts","3");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        // Setup port forwarding from localhost to the Redis server
        // Local port is ephemeral (given by the OS)
        // Jedis connects to localhost using the local port
        port = session.setPortForwardingL( 0, HOST, PORT );
        jedis = new Jedis( "127.0.0.1", port );
      } catch ( JSchException e ) {
        // Proper error handling omitted
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    } 

    public void disconnect() {
      jedis.disconnect();
      try {
        session.delPortForwardingL( port );
        session.disconnect();            
      } catch ( JSchException e ) {
        // Proper error handling omitted
        System.out.println(e);
      } 
    }

    public void mytest( int n ) {
     for ( int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
      jedis.set("k" + k, "value"+k);
     }
     System.out.println("Read: "+jedis.get("k0") );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestTunnel obj = new TestTunnel();
      obj.mytest(10);
      obj.disconnect();
    }
 }
```

It works fine, but please note there is an overhead due to the tunnel. The overhead is very low when the network is slow (the Internet for instance). On a fast LAN (1 GbE), it is much more noticeable: the latency can be multiplied by up to 3 when the tunnel is used. The maximum throughput the Redis server can sustain is also impacted. On server-side, the sshd daemon takes some CPU (more than Redis itself).

That said, I don't think raw performance matters much for a 2-tier application.

Answer (score 2):

Note: There's an SSL version of redis called SSL-REDIS which can be found on github:
https://github.com/bbroerman30/ssl-redis 2.6ish

https://github.com/tritondigital/ssl-redis 2.4ish

With this and modifying the Jedis Java client, SSL authentication *could* be achieved.